# Best way of importing data into a MySQL database which was exported to a single XML file using joins

Tags: mysql, xml, import, export

I am trying to write an export/import facility using MySQL and XML. The data would typically be exported by one registered user and imported back into the database by another user.

The data lives in different tables and is associated with an id which is specified in the SQL "where" clause of the export query.

I can export the data into a single file by running the SQL query with joins.

What is the "neatest" way of allowing the other user to import the data from the exported file?

My problem is the records in the file contain fields which are only used in certain tables and cause the SQL query to fail when reference is made to a field which is not used in the table where the data is being inserted.

I can get around this by writing queries which specify the fields to be inserted but this will incur a significant maintenance overhead and a vulnerability if these maintenance updates to the import queries are overlooked during application development.

This is a "best practice" question.

### Update

What I did in the end to overcome the problem associated with linked tables and the extraction and insertion of auto-incrementing primary ids was to export the rows intact. Another words all fields including primary ids were added to the export file. Then when importing the data back in, in order to add the rows from the linked tables correctly, my code saved all the old ids from the different tables and then inserted the rows without these old ids. This involved using the old ids to properly link the data from the different tables. New ids are generated by auto-increment. This was a bit involved but at least no non-id fields were handled. This will make the code more robust and resistant to breakage when new data fields get added during application development.

My code is shown below. Please note that $file will be created using dialogs.

```
    if($option=='Export test'){
        // ----
        // Exports an xml file. This includes all primary ids
        // ----
        $file='export.xml';
        $xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>'."\n";
        $xml.="<".$database_connect.">\n";
        file_put_contents($file,$xml);
        $rows=returnTestQuestionsPlus($template_id);
        $table='test_questions';
        exportRowsToXMLFile($table,$rows,$file);
        foreach($rows as $row){
            $question_id=$row['question_id'];
            $rows2=returnTestAnswersPlus($question_id);
            $table='test_answers';
            exportRowsToXMLFile($table,$rows2,$file);
        }
        $xml="</".$database_connect.">";
        file_put_contents($file,$xml,FILE_APPEND);
        header("Location: select_template.php?info_message=The $object6 has been exported to $file.");
        exit;
    }
    if($option=='Import test'){
        // ----
        // Gets xml file content. This includes all primary ids.
        // ----
        $file='export.xml';
        $xml=file_get_contents($file);
        $xml=str_ireplace(chr(10),'',$xml);
        $xml=str_ireplace(chr(13),'',$xml);
        $xml=new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
        $tables = json_decode(json_encode((array)$xml), TRUE);
        // ----
        // Removes primary ids and then inserts data into the database.
        // ----
        foreach($tables as $table=>$rows){
            foreach($rows as $row){
                if($table=='test_questions'){
                    $old_question_ids[]=$row['question_id'];
                }
            }
        }
        foreach($tables as $table=>$rows){
            foreach($rows as $row){
                if($table=='test_questions'){
                    $question_id=$row['question_id'];
                    unset($row['question_id']);
                    unset($row['sort_id']);
                    unset($row['template_id']);
                    $sql="select count(*) as number from test_questions";
                    $row2=returnRow(__LINE__,$sql);
                    extract($row2);
                    $sort_id=$number+1;
                    $row['sort_id']=$sort_id;
                    $row['template_id']=$template_id;
                    $results=insertRow2('test_questions',$row);
                    extract($results);
                    $new_question_ids[]=$id;
                }
            }
        }
        $test_answers_rows=array();
        foreach($tables as $table=>$rows){
            foreach($rows as $row){
                if($table=='test_answers'){
                    $question_id=$row['question_id'];
                    foreach($old_question_ids as $key=>$old_question_id){
                        if($question_id==$old_question_id)$new_question_id=$new_question_ids[$key];
                    }
                    unset($row['question_id']);
                    unset($row['answer_id']);
                    $row['question_id']=$new_question_id;
                    $test_answers_rows[]=$row;
                }
            }
        }
        insertMultipleRowsPDP('test_answers',$test_answers_rows);
        header("Location: select_template.php?info_message=The $object6 has been imported from $file.");
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: Why not just use the built-in `SELECT...TO OUTFILE` and `LOAD DATA INFILE`? It seems to me that converting to XML is just adding a layer of complexity you may not need.

Comment: @Mike, Thanks for your comment and I will bear that in mind. However, the problem is not file format such as csv or xml but how to extract data in the required fields when importing - or have I missed something here?

Comment: `LOAD DATA INFILE` requires you to set a destination for every field in the input file, but you can assign an incoming field to a variable which you can then discard. Thus, you can select exactly which fields you import, and you can also manipulate these variables and assign them to columns, allowing you to edit the fields on import.

Comment: @Mike I would like to reduce the risk of the export/import facility breaking when a field is added to a table during the course of developing another aspect of the application. Perhaps this risk would be reduced if field names were retrieved and compiled from the information_schema. Also in order to avoid the need for script changes to exclude fieldnames in the file for a particular table, perhaps the export file should consist of different sections where each section contains data for a specific table. Is this best practice or is there a completely different & less involved approach to this?

Comment: `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` allows you to specify which columns to transfer. `LOAD DATA INFILE` allows you to specify where incoming fields are assigned. Provided the content of the transfer file is fixed, adding additional columns to source or destination tables shouldn't affect the transfer process. You may need to be careful about default values for new columns. Of course, if you need to transfer more columns that will affect the transfer process, but I doubt you can code around every possible change.